# Story with the maharam schick

Tags: history, death, wedding, story-identification, kittel

I'm looking for where a certain story with the maharam Schick is printed.
It goes as follows : the ruler of the maharam Schicks area wished to see a Jewish wedding and ordered that one take place in his palace. He observed the ceremony and asked what the *kittel* that the groom wears is for. In response, the maharam Schick said that it is to remind the groom of death since he will be buried in a kittel as well when he dies.
In other words a wedding, as happy a time as it is for the new couple, they still need a reminder in mortality that serves as a lesson that life is not all fun and games.

Comment: I don't get the significance of this story...

Comment: As the goyim say "till death do us part."

Comment: @Shababnik I think robev's problem is why does one need a story involving maharam Schick, just to say that the groom wears a _kittel_ at his wedding ceremony to remind himself of death, since he will be buried in it as well when he dies. What does the story add to the _minhag_, or it's purpose? Wouldn't they have been known if not for the stroy?

Comment: I understand his question, but don't have an answer. What's the point of any story? Just write the lesson of the story in one sentence... either way I know it's written somewhere and am trying to find it